# How do I combine standard errors when making a prediction about a wider sample?

Tags: r, modeling, standard-error

Imagine I have a dataset that I want to use to predict a variable 'var':

```
set.seed(0)

dataset <- tibble(sex = sample(c('M', 'F'), 100, TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(var = ifelse(sex == 'M', 150 + rnorm(100, 0, 10), 
                      120 + rnorm(100, 0, 10)))
```

I want to then predict the total of 'var' from a larger dataset:

```
dataset_full <- tibble(sex = sample(c('M', 'F'), 1000, TRUE))
```

I can use predict to get the central estimate for this value:

```
var_model <- lm(var ~ sex, 
dataset)

summary(var_model)

sum(predict(var_model, dataset_full))
```

But how should I approach getting a standard error for this new total value?

I've tried:

```
standard_errors <- predict(var_model, dataset_full, se.fit = T)$se.fit

sum(sqrt(standard_errors^2))
```

I.e. sum the standard errors in quadrature? My rough understanding is that this assumes the standard errors are independent, but obviously if the model is wrong, that will affect all the errors.

I suspect I could bootstrap an answer - but I'm interested in whether there's an analytical way to do this.  Does it involve a covariance matrix?